# App is crashing after saving value to Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am trying to program my first app with Android Studio (with java), and am stuck.
The app should take input from the user (using Plain Text) and then keep it and display it the next time the app is launched.
I want to be able to keep data between launches of the app, and from what I understood, the most effective and elegant way, is to use Shared Preferences. But every time I press on the button that saves the text to Shared Preferences, the app crashes.

This is my code:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    
    private final String PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    private final String INPUT = "user_input";
    private final String MEMO = "memo";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    private void saveData(View view) {
        TextView input = view.findViewById(R.id.user_input);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(MEMO, input.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        TextView memos = view.findViewById(R.id.memos);
        memos.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(MEMO, ""));

        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveData(view);
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT: my crash logs:

```
    Process: com.example.myfirstapplication, PID: 2322
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myfirstapplication.FirstFragment.saveData(FirstFragment.java:32)
        at com.example.myfirstapplication.FirstFragment.access$000(FirstFragment.java:14)
        at com.example.myfirstapplication.FirstFragment$1.onClick(FirstFragment.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7161)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7138)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:811)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27419)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Would be delighted to see if anyone has a solution to my problem!

Comment: Please add your crash logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a debugger you can see that in the `saveData` function the `input` variable remains `Null`. In order to fix this issue, replace:

```
TextView input = view.findViewById(R.id.user_input);
```

With:

```
TextView input = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user_input);
```

You may check the value of `input` to verify the desired string is indeed there.

p.s. Now the use of the `view` parameter in your function is redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

when you press the button, you call saveData() method. but you set button view as argument not root view. you should do like this

```
view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
        // change onClick's parameter name from view to v
            saveData(view);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to use view from the outside scope, because it's accessed from within inner class and it should be declared final.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the assignment of your `SharedPrefrence` object as a `Fragment` field will definitely raise an exception, because it's called before the fragment is attached to your activity, and in terms of the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating), the [`onAttach()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)) callback is not invoked yet, so, `getActivity()` will be null.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And the exception that you'll get will be something like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FirstFragment{cfb327} (a42392bd-ee02-48a2-9d61-aaa8c455bb10)} not attached to an activity.
```

To solve this replace the below line

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

And you already initialize it in `onViewCreated()` method.

Comment: I still crashes, and the error is:
```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference```